# ajax call to asp web servers gives is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. error

Tags: asp.net, jquery, cross-domain

i created a function that do ajax call to my localhost webservers

And i gets this error message from console. Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
this is my web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

  </system.webServer>
```

this is my JS function:

```
function doAjax()
{
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: "http://localhost:5181/WebService1.asmx/UpdateReport",

     data: "{'test_description':'" + TestCaseDiscription + "', "
           + "'test_id':'" + id + "',"
           + "'tester_name':'" + TesterName + "',"
           + "'test_url':'" + test_url + "'}",

    dataType: "json",
    error: function (err){ 
                alert(err)
        },

    success: function (data){
                    alert(data)
    }

});
}
```

and this is my webservis

```
[WebMethod]
public string UpdateReport(string test_description, string test_id, string test_url, string tester_name)
{
    report report = new report();

    report.test_description = test_description;
    report.test_id = test_id;
    report.test_url = test_url;
    report.tester_name = tester_name;


    if (report.UpdateDataBase())
        return "correct";

    return "Sorry";
}
```

Any ideas why its not working?
i have been reading that this issue appear beucase cross domain ajax calls.
but i have no idea how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not a server side issue, it is the client. You can't make calls for content from a different domain...including a different security level ie ssl or a sub domain or socket!.

There is a work around though, JSONP. This allows you to call a script to execute as a call back function. The response from the sever needs to be either wrapped in the callback function sent in the request or if you use jquery, lt will handle the dirty work for you. See example

```
       `jQuery.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: payload,
        url: "http://someotherdomain.com?callback=?",
        jsonp: true})
        .done(function (response, status, request) {
            if (response.success)
                processResponse(response.success);
            console.log("done");
        })
        .fail(function (response, status, request) {
            console.log("fail");

        })
        .always(function (response) {
            console.log("always");

        })`
```

Server Side php

```
$response = array("key" => 'A Message');
$success = $success?"success":"failure";
$response = json_encode($response);
echo $_GET['callback'].'(' . "{\"".$success ."\" : ".$response."}" . ')';
```

Comment: thanks for the respond, so what you saying that i cannt do ajax call like this? only by callback?

Comment: [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP[/link] Yes exactly. However using this method you can do a lot. [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy[/link]

Comment: i still gets block , maybe because the site is https?

Comment: One of the key components of JSONP is the callback=? in the query string, did you remember to do that? Are you doing a JSONP call? Are you still trying to make a regular ajax call back to your server? Do they match on all accounts? http, port, domain

Comment: I have changed the data type to JSONP and the type to Get,
and now its Working!!!!

but its diable the https from the site. do you know why?

thanks alot !!!!

Comment: Everything should work fine if both domains are secure. If you try and make a insecure call from a secure domain, that will violate the integrity of ssl and depending on the browser give you grief. Make sure your certs are both working and in their respective stores as well.